# How can I post a login form to a legacy server (without Ajax)?

Tags: angular, forms, http, authentication

My team and I have built an Angular SPA alongside our legacy web platform. We're now migrating the login experience to the SPA, but we're not able to refactor the auth server just yet. We'd like to do a conventional HTTP post request (form submit inside our ngSubmit function) to the existing server using our model-driven (reactive) Angular form.

How can we do so without Ajax? We expect to need an old-school page refresh to happen as the auth server redirects back to the Angular app. Let me know if any code would be helpful, but it's pretty standard stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access component element as an  [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) in constructor of component. This has a property `nativeElement` which exposes dom node and methods. Then call `submit()` on the form element

```js
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core'

export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {  
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}

  onSubmit(){
    // query your `<form>` element
    const form = this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelector('form')
    // add any missing properties not in template attributes
    form.action = 'form/process/path';
    form.method='POST';
    // browser default submit
    form.submit();    
  }
 ....
}
```